# Why is autocomplete for my Git coming up with weird commands?

Tags: git, bash

Can anyone help me out? These are some really weird Git commands...

[image: screenshot]

I looked through my .bash_profile and then took a look at the Git bash-completion file, but it was way too big for me to figure out on my own.

Comment: which shell are you using?

Comment: That is some color coding gone wrong. The `^[` is an escape sequence, and the rest is some [terminal codes](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/terminalcodes) primarily for producing colors. If you ignore the `^[[m^[[K` part from that output, the built-in commands are all completely normal.

Comment: It looks like the autocomplete file has a bunch of extraneous control characters. I don't know how to fix it or what put them there.

Comment: The problem is with your terminal or with your terminal settings. Bash believes that your terminal supports standard color-setting escape sequences, but it doesn't. What terminal are you running bash in, and what is the value of `$TERM`?

Comment: Most likely because of the terminal you are using or the shell you are running. If you are running bash then it is most likely because your colors are messed up. I would say just reinstall bash or try `source /etc/profile`

Comment: @Jepessen Using iTerm

Comment: @poke Yeah that realization came to me too.